How to hide cut | copy | Paste menu on double tap or long press in input box on chromium
I had an integrated Chromium application where I needed to hide the menu that appeared on double-tap or long press on a POS device or touch laptop, as shown in the image below.
I tried the code below, which works only on div elements. However, we need it to be disabled for text boxes as well.
 {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
 }



You can't. The clipboard options are controlled by the OS at a level that JS doesn't have access to.

Thanks for the info @RoryMcCrossan, But is it possible to disable at the browser level.?

This question is similar to: Disabling the context menu on long taps on Android. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you are using your own Chromium fork then you can modify the source code to do so
